# Improved dimension subgroups

Tags: gr.group-theory, group-rings

Given a group $G$,
 one can define
 (see below)
 a descending sequence of subgroups
 $K^s(G)$, $s=1,2,\dots$,
 satisfying
 $$
 \gamma^s(G)\subseteq K^s(G)\subseteq D^s(G),
 $$
 where
 $\gamma^s(G)$ is the lower central series and
 $D^s(G)$ are the dimension subgroups.

The question is whether
 $K^s(G)=\gamma^s(G)$
 for all $G$ and $s$.

Definition of $K^s(G)$.
 Take an epimorphism $p\colon F\to G$ from a free group;
 let $R\subseteq F$ be its kernel.
 Consider
 the group ring $\mathbb ZF$ and
 the additive subgroup
 (not an ideal)
 $$
 \Delta_F^s+\Delta_R\subseteq\mathbb ZF,
 $$
 where
 $\Delta_F^s$ is the $s$th power of the augmentation ideal and
 $\Delta_R$ is the augmentation ideal of the subring
 $\mathbb ZR\subseteq\mathbb ZF$.
 Consider the preimage
 $$
 L=i^{-1}(1+\Delta_F^s+\Delta_R)\subseteq F,
 $$
 where $i\colon F\to\mathbb ZF$ is the canonical embedding.
 One easily verifies that
 $L$ is a subgroup containing $R$.
 It follows that
 $$L=p^{-1}(K)$$
 for some gubgroup $K\subseteq G$.
 This $K$ does not depend on the choice of $F$ and $p$.
 We define $K^s(G)=K$.

Comment: Did you see this: https://www.revistas.usp.br/resenhasimeusp/article/viewFile/75101/78665 ?

Comment: No, I did not. It may be useful. Thank you.